# What is best Practices for Hosting Tor Onion Hidden Service?

Tags: configuration, whonix, qubes

I want to host Tor onion hidden service, I want to know what is the best technique to host it, can someone helps me with the below questions

What is the best server operating system for hosting Tor onion hidden service ( Debian - Fedora - Ubuntu  - Red Hat Linux - Gentoo - SUSE Linux - Ipredia OS - Black Arch Linux - Discreete Linux - Linux Kodachi - Parrot Security OS - Mofo Linux - Subgraph OS - TrueOS - FreeBSD -  Qubes-Whonix)

Can Qubes-Whonix use it as server OS for hosting Tor onion hidden service?

Is Whonix mandatory for anonymity and privacy or can I just use any other Linux distribution?

If Whonix Mandatory for anonymity and privacy which approach below should I use to host tor onion hidden service?

1)Linux with VirtualBox
2)Qubes-Whonix
3)Linux with KVM

Is it safe to use a VPN like NordVPN with TOR for more anonymity and privacy or just Tor?

Is mini pc like intel nuc or kingdel good for being used as server machine for hosting Tor onion hidden service? what is hardware System Requirements (CPU & GPU & Ram)?

What can I do in PHP or Laravel framework configuration to ensure it is anonymous and compatible with tor and don't exploit anything to show identity and to be anonymous and safe?

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, and there aren't good answers for any of them. My suggestion is to spend a few months trying all of these tools to learn how they work and what advantages/disadvantages they have, because there is no single answer that applies for everyone. The best answer is usually "use what you're most familiar with".

Comment: any Linux distribution is enough to host TOR Hidden services.i will sugess Ubunut but make sure with code it should be complete penertest and there shoudn't be open any request for 127.0.0.1 You can more secure with VPN but should be trusted provider.

Comment: yes you should always use a VPN or better yet a decentralized VPN. faster and more secure check it out as far as OP I dont know im in that camp looking for a nuc box or some other computer that will work anything else let me me know if you have qustion